# How do I place GestureDetector inside a ToggleButtons

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, mobile

I am trying to render a `ToggleButtons` where each button member inside it will run `callback1` on click, and also contains its own `GestureDetector` widget, something like a `Setting icon` at the right end of it, and it will execute a different callback (`callback2` from snippet below) when gets pressed.

Here is the code for the UI I am trying to create:

```dart
return LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
    return ToggleButtons(
      constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
        width: constraints.maxWidth,
        height: Sizes.p48,
      ),
      isSelected: isItemSelected,
      direction: Axis.vertical,
      textStyle: AppTextStyles.labelL4_14pxMedium,
      renderBorder: false,
      onPressed: callback1, /// <<<---- Parent callback gets executed all the time 
      children: items
          .map(
            (item) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: Sizes.p12,
              ),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    child: Text(
                      item.name,
                      maxLines: 1,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: callback2, /// <<<--- this never run 
                    child: const Icon(Icons.settings),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
    );
  },
);
```

But no matter where I clicked, always the `callback1` got executed.

I was looking for solutions and knew about `HitTestBehavior`, but it doesn't seem to be the answer for my situation.
Inside my callback2 was a `print` statement, and I made sure to watch the log during trying to press the icon, but it had never run
Also tried to place breakpoint on `callback2`, but no change

Comment: ToggleButtons( onPressed: (int i){ if (i==0){ callback1();} else if(i==1){callback2();} }) // use onPressed's *i to use as u like

Comment: your solution won't work, where does the `i` come from? If you define it yourself then there is no way to contextualize it

Comment: *onPressed gives u an integer, hold ur mouse on it to see

Comment: thanks for your reply, but the `i` you referred to only helps point out the index of the toggle button that got clicked inside the parent ToggleButtons, from the snippet above `i` is the item's index. That will not help if I want to know whether my GestureDetector got clicked, and from the question, I also had problem with clicking on my GestureDetector, `callback2` never executed